# How to define boolean field for a rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

I want to add a boolean field ("is_public") to the table "my_model". Currently, I can use this:

```
class AddPublicToDream < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :my_model, :is_public, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :my_model, :is_public, :string
  end      
end
```

Then I can assign "true" or "false" to mymodel.is_public in controllers.

Can I substitute :string with :boolean to achieve the same effect? Would it save some database space compared to :string?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes, you can use `:boolean` for this, and yes it will also save database space.

Comment: Thanks dude~ But I tested in console. It complains "NoMethodError: undefined method `is_public=' for #<Class:0x1036f3980>
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1008:in `method_missing'
 from (irb):16
"

Comment: @fmttm: Have you run the migration? If you look in your schema.rb, is the is_public field now listed for your my_model table?

Comment: yea sometimes (with heroku at least) migrations take time to go into effect

Answer (score 23):

Change the type attribute to `:boolean` and run `rake db:migrate` again. You should be able to call, for example:

```
Dream.is_public?  # returning true or false depending whether is set.
```

Comment: Thanks. I learn from you that Dream.is_public? would be automatically generated by rails. coool~~~